# Condition for: A simple quotient metric induced by surjective map + equivalence relation

Tags: gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, quotient-space

Let $X$ be a metric space and let $f:X\rightarrow Z$ be a surjective map onto some set $Z$.  Define the pseudo-metric $d_f$ on $Z$ by:
$$
d_f(z_1,z_2)\triangleq \inf_{\underset{f(x_i)=z_i}{x_i\in X}}
\,
d_X(x_1,x_2),
$$
Under what conditions is $d_f$ a metric on $Z/\sim$ where $z\sim \tilde{z}$ if and only if $f^{-1}[z]\cap f^{-1}[\tilde{z}]\neq \emptyset$?

---

*It seems as though we only need to show that
$d_f([x],[z])\leq d_f([x],[y])+d_f([y],[z])$?*

Comment: You need any two distance fibers to have a positive distance to ensure the separation condition. The triangle inequality seems less obvious to characterize in a nontrivial way.

Comment: Can you reveal the context of your question? I have seen a lot of related (but different) constructions in papers by Wenger, Young, Petrunin, Zust and others. If your research is related to this work, let me know.

Comment: Yes: Say $\emptyset\neq Y,W\subset G$ is a Banach Algebra.  Let $X=\sqcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} (Y,W)^{n}$  and $f$ is the map sending any $(y_1,w_1,\dots,y_n,w_n)\in X$ to $\sum_{k=1}^n y_kw_k$, and let $Z$ be the image of this map when restricted to $X$ (instead of on $\bigcup_n\,G^n$).  I have a good handle on the metric on $Y$ and $W$ (these happen to be separable.. while $G$ is not) and I want to use it to meaningfully give a new metric on $Z/\sim$ which I can control.